# Do a HTTP POST instead of a GET

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, http-method

The WebService I'm trying to use is SOAP and receives only the HTTP method POST on its requests, but for some reason, I'm not being able to make that happen and it's sending only GET.

I've been loosely following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

I've thought that it wouldn’t be the case of the wrong method, but I've tried via Postman with the logged envelope and it worked fine, also this:

[debugger image with GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpQWt.png)

This is how I've done it:

```java
package com.example.ws;

import com.demo.partner.wsdl.ObjectFactory;
import com.demo.partner.wsdl.StoreInformation;
import com.example.util.PartnerWSHttpHeaderCallBack;
import com.example.util.SoapUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;

public class StoreInformationClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StoreInformationClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory objectFactory;

    public StoreInformation getStoreInformation() {

        StoreInformation storeInformation = objectFactory.createStoreInformation();
        storeInformation.setStoreID("99633");

        return  (StoreInformation) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive("https://aurl.com/api/ws.wsdl", SoapUtils.buildEnvelope(storeInformation, StoreInformation.class),
                new PartnerWSHttpHeaderCallBack());
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.configuration;

import com.demo.partner.wsdl.ObjectFactory;
import com.example.ws.StoreInformationClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.demo.partner.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public StoreInformationClient countryClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        StoreInformationClient client = new StoreInformationClient();
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectFactory objectFactory() {
        return new ObjectFactory();
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.util;

import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceMessageCallback;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.context.TransportContext;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.context.TransportContextHolder;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PartnerWSHttpHeaderCallBack implements WebServiceMessageCallback {

    @Override
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic definitelyABase64value");
        headers.put("SOAPAction", "http://www.partner.com/action/GetStoreInformation");
        headers.put("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        addRequestHeader(headers);
    }

    private void addRequestHeader(Map<String, String> headers) {
        TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
        WebServiceConnection connection = context.getConnection();

        if (connection instanceof HttpUrlConnection) {
            HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection) connection;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
                String k = entry.getKey();
                String v = entry.getValue();
                try {
                    conn.addRequestHeader(k, v);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that get is sent instead post? Do you have some error?

Comment: I get the same error that when I do it through Postman, and you can see the image that the connection is using the GET method. I've tried setting it in the PartnerWSHttpHeaderCallBack, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at both 6 api and 8 api docs for spring and find that way is almost impossible (if not it is impossible) because as you are finding there does not appear to be a method in that hierarchy set of classes and interfaces (IN YOUR FORM OF CODE) a sensible coherent way of converting the http connection to "POST" , it will only send "GET".
I do understand that the HttpUrlConnection is not java.net and is an org.spring. but the spring connections must be obtained through extensions and the instance context of the connected objects.
the spring framework documentation seems erroneous also because it shows no-where org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportConstants and org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpTransportConstants are implemented.
Niether taking a look searching the web.
All i can suggest "trying" is this **however "Spring.org project" needs to clearly document how to set the constants for those interfaces AND if anything actually implements them !**

```
/*
            org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportConstants
            import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpTransportConstants
            */
            
            HttpTransportConstants httCxt = ((HttpTransportConstants)TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext());
            // perhaps httCxt."METHOD_POST";
        httCxt.METHOD_POST;
    // no really, there should be an implementing class in the .transport packages that uses and sets this however i could not locate one throughout the ws classes and interfaces.
    // all interface variables are static and final (because interfaces are abstract they can be cast together)
            TransportContext context = (TransportContext)httCxt;
```

Here is an article that seems to have some way alike
https://pretagteam.com/question/soap-request-to-webservice-with-java
however i think they use a java.net HttpURLConnection

*There is a similar HttpURLConnection object in spring*

*** The spring docs also do not show full hierarchy on identical classes and interfaces**

```
org.springframework.ws.transport.http
Class HttpUrlConnection IMPLEMENTS org.springframework.ws.transport
Interface WebServiceConnection

The following worked many years back for applets and since finding ambiguous docs naming it appears this would work (or be immensely close)

To make a org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection

make a protected method 


protected org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection makeConnHttp(String uuu){
    java.net.URL urli = new java.net.URL(uuu);
    Java.net.UrlConnection urlcon = new Java.net.UrlConnection(urli);
    Java.net.HttpUrlConnection netUrl = (Java.net.HttpUrlConnection)urlcon;
    netUrl.setRequestMethod("POST");
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection wsUrlConn = new org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection(netUrl);
    return (org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection)wsUrlConn;
    }
    
    public org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection getWSconnectionHttp(String uuu){
    return (org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection)makeConnHttp(uuu);
    }

// spring 2.1.4 HttpUrlConnection is also a WebServiceConnection
org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceConnection wdConnsvc = (org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceConnection)getWSconnectionHttp(uuu);
```

It is not known to me whether the api process calls open()/close()  on UrLConnection or that has to be done manually.

**Where your code goes wrong**
Notice how your code gets a TransportContext and it gets a WebServiceConnection.
That produced object instance is a SEPERATE object instance not related to the later constructed spring framework HttpUrlConnection.
You could open the connection but it is not the WebServiceConnection object constructed with the transport context.

The problem is the org spring HttpUrlConnection IS( a WebServiceConnection) also by polymorphism , so you do not need to obtain a WebServiceConnection because you would have that from creating a org.spring HttpUrlConnection.
However an org spring HttpUrlConnection must be fed an implementing coded java.net.HttpUrlConnection for the actual networking, the org spring HttpUrlConnection is more of a joiner wrapper for obtaining and managing data bound to the java.net.HttpUrlConnection and the containers registrations of the service endpoints.

Your code would require joining the two parts by replacing any instance of org.springframework....HttpUrlConnection with an/or-the externally created HttpUrlConnection using lava.lang.reflect.

However, the best method for binding objectes in that problem is extend from the class org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection to prevent binding and access problems.